# Bishop movement in chess

Tags: python, python-3.6, chess

I'm doing a chess game for a school project in python3.
I'm stuck at the bishop movement. I did everything move for all the pieces but the bishop is really hard. Here is how I code my board:

```
board=[["R1W","C1W","F1W","K1W","D1W","F2W","C2W","R2W"],
       ["P1W","P2W","P3W","P4W","P5W","P6W","P7W","P8W"],
       ["___","___","___","___","___","___","___","___"],
       ["___","___","___","___","___","___","___","___"],
       ["___","___","___","___","___","___","___","___"],
       ["___","___","___","___","___","___","___","___"],
       ["P1N","P2N","P3N","P4N","P5N","P6N","P7N","P8N"],
       ["R1N","C1N","F1N","D1N","K1N","F2N","C2N","R2N"]]
```

and here is how I program my bishop:

```
def fou_valide(piece,l,m,c,n):
    if piece[0]=="F":
        if (abs(m-l)+abs(n-c))%2==0 and l!=m and  n!=c and board_fou_dame[l][c]==board_fou_dame[m][n] and abs(l-m)==abs(c-n):
            if m>l and n>c:
                for x in range(l+1,m):# on scanne les cases ou va passer la piece si elle ne passe par-dessus une pieces en effet elle ne peut pas sauter au dessus d\'une autre piece
                    for y in range(c+1,n):
                        if board[x][y]!="___":
                            print ("faux")
                            return False
                return True
            elif m>l and n<c:
                for z in range(l+1,m):# on scanne les cases ou va passer la piece si elle ne passe par-dessus une pieces en effet elle ne peut pas sauter au dessus d\'une autre piece
                    for j in range(c-1,n,-1):
                        if board[z][j]!="___":
                            print ("fau")
                            return False
```

That's just half the code only `l`, `m`, `n`, and `c` are changing.
My problem is that even though `n>c`, it shows `"fau"` instead of `"faux"`

Here is how I ask for position:

```
l = int(input("ligne de selection?:\n"))-1 #on demande au joueur la ligne de la piece a selectionné
c = int(input("colonne de selection?:\n"))-1#on demande au joueur la colonne de la piece a selectionné
m = int(input("ligne de destination ?:\n"))-1#on demande au joueur la ligne ou il veut pose la piece
n = int(input("colonne de destination?:\n"))-1#on demande au joueur la colonne ou il veut pose la piece
piece = board[l][c] # piece correspond a la piece selectionné
```

Comment: Wow! That's a pretty cool task!

Comment: `print ("fau")` maybe need to change to `print('faux')` ?

Comment: I don't think that's it @zimdero

Comment: Correct me Adam if I am wrong. What you are trying to do is: Check if there is a bishop at the start index than check if that bishop can move to the destination.

Comment: You did rooks and queens, but bishops are hard? Sounds like the same kind of problem.

Comment: I use fau, faux so that when i launch the program i know where the bug is

Comment: The thing is that when i move from right to left. For example i take the F1W ( coordonate are [1][3]) i move it to [6][8] the program print "fau". It should print "faux" because n>c and m>l

Comment: I did rooks, the queens use the fonctiun of the rooks and bishop so to finish queen i need the bishop to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to Bruno L, it now works fine, here is the code for the bishop that i used, this is a simplified version :

```
def fou_valide(piece,l,m,c,n,):
if piece[0]=="F":#F in french stand for bishop, "Fou", 
    if l!=m and  n!=c  and abs(l-m)==abs(c-n): #the condition for the bishop movement
        dl = sign(m - l)#it get the me direction of the movement
        dc = sign(n - c)
        x, y = c + dc, l + dl
        while x != n and y != m:#This check if they are any non-empty cell on the way
            if board[y][x] != '___': # non empty cell
                return False
            x += dc
            y += dl
        return True
    return False
return True
```

Here is the sign function:

```
def sign(z):
if z >= 0:
    return 1  
else:
    return -1
```

Comment: Just a last thing. By modifying the sign to return `0` if `c == 0`, you can use the same code for the rook and the queen, You just need to slightly change the conditions in the two first if.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, `piece` is useles since you have `l` and `c`.
In your function, you have to verify four things.

1) that the piece is indeed a bishop
2) that `l` and `c` are differnt from `m` and `c`
3) that they are on the same diagonal
4) that the cells between the two are free

The 4) is the hardest unless you remark that the direction you need to check is `(sign(m - l), sign(n - c))`. There's no need to write a different piece of code for each direction or each color.

EDIT: There's no built-in `sign` function, you need to write it yourself.

```
def sign(n):
    return 1 if n >= 0 else -1
```

Then, you can check the cells with a single while loop that works for any direction.

```
def can_eat(l, c, m, n):
    dl = sign(m - l)
    dc = sign(n - c)
    x, y = c + dc, l + dl
    while x != n and y != m:
        if board[y][x] != '___': # non empty cell
            return False
        x += dc
        y += dl
    return True
```

Comment: not only the question author will read this, use English please

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I switched to english.

Comment: sign(n-c) is the same as saying n>c or n<c. The thing is that when i move from right to left. For example i take the F1W ( coordonate are [1][3]) i move it to [6][8] the program print "fau". It should print "faux" because n>c and m>l

Comment: It is not the same because it's more general. In your code, you have four ifs, one for each direction. By setting `dx = sign(n - c)` and  `dy = sign(m - l)`, you can simply check the cells from `(l + dy, c + dx)` to `(m, n)` by steps of `(dy, dx)`. It works the same for all directions.

Comment: I didn't get what you meant. Could you,please, write it down in code . What is this function sign ? Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Ok so i put your code, it works, i understand it but i have the same problem that i had before, i think our code was similar but yours is smaller. When i take for example F1W ( coordonate are [1][3]) i move it to [6][8], then it shows that i can't move there because there is a piece there. There are no piece on the way and i move P4W before. It only works if i move it to the third line, then i can move to [6][8]

Comment: oh my god, thanks a lot it works perfectly, i'm gonna post the complete code in the answer